# Landsat L1GS product processing to change detection analysis ready state

Tags: landsat, accuracy, topography, time-series

At high latitude area of Svalbard Norway, one can find Landsat 8 data processed to L1TP level. With previous Landsat missions, this is not the case. Landsat 7 data are processed to L1Gt level and Landsat 1 to 5 data are processed to L1GS level.

https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-levels-processing

Target would be to get these products to state, where time series for change detection analysis could be composed. Spatial inaccuracies could be mitigated with automated co-registration of images. I thought this could be done with AROSICS software, using the L8 OLI L1TP -data as reference images.

https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/9/7/676

https://pypi.org/project/arosics/

When the imagery reliably aligns, I have understood that L1Gt data could be used for change detection analysis. This leaves the question of L1Gs data. Can one then employ topographic correction with a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) to correct for relief displacement in the new co-registered L1Gs images? Or does the previous geometric corrections done to L1Gs data obstruct this process?